# Changing the entity relationship type from "To One" to "To Many" with code?

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, uisegmentedcontrol

**Edit:** After reading please look at my comment to see where I'm at now :)*

So I have a UISegementedControl with newest,price,title, and item type and for some reason everytime I switch tabs the itemType label only keeps one of the labels for the item type.

**Example:** 3 Cells of itemType Electronics all with the same itemType label, then when you switch to another segment, only the newest Electronic cell itemType Label stays.

I have no idea why it's doing this after reviewing my code and researching.

Note: I am using CoreData

`segmentChange` Function

```
@IBAction func segmentChange(_ sender: Any) {
    //segment control function
    attemptFetch()
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

`attemptFetch` function:

```
func attemptFetch() {
    // function needed to fetch and display items

    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Item> = Item.fetchRequest()
    //tells what item or entity you're tracking
    let dateSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "created", ascending: false)
    let priceSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "price", ascending: true)
    let titleSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "title", ascending: true)
    let itemTypeSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "type", ascending: true)

    if segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {

        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [dateSort]

    } else if segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {

        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [priceSort]

    } else if segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 2 {

        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [titleSort]

    } else if segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 3 {

        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [itemTypeSort]
    }



    let controller = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    //instantiates NSFetchedResultsController

    controller.delegate = self
    //tells the functions what to do and listen 

    self.controller = controller

    do {
    // attempting fetch of item
        try controller.performFetch()

    } catch {
        let error = error as NSError
        print("\(error)")

    }

}
```

My `savePressed` function when you create a new item:

```
@IBAction func savePressed(_ sender: Any) {
    //saves to disk/"database"

    var item: Item!
    let picture = Image(context: context)
    picture.image = thumbImage.image




    if itemToEdit == nil {
        // if no objects then create new item
        item = Item(context: context)
        //insert entity into context

    } else {
        //takes existing cell and lets you edit it
        item = itemToEdit

    }

    item.toImage = picture
    // item entity to image entity

    if let title = titleField.text {

        item.title = title
    }

    if let price = priceField.text {

        item.price = (price as NSString).doubleValue
        // lets use properties of NSString and convert to double
    }

    if let details = detailsField.text {

        item.details = details
    }

    item.toStore = stores[storePicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
    item.toItemType = itemTypes[storePicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)]
    // relationship from item to store or vise versa is picked (component is the # of columns)

    ad.saveContext()

    _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)



}
```

Comment: I figured out that the reason it's not working is the relationship from Item to "toItemType" was set to one and not many. 

The problem I have now is that when I change it, it says "UserInfo={entity=Item, property=toItemType, reason=Can not map from a to-many to a to-one relationship}]"

Comment: Still trying to figure out how to manually make a relationship you've already created many to many instead of one to one

Comment: Normally you do that by creating a new version of the data model. Why do you want to do it in code?

Comment: @TomHarrington I have a label on my table view cell and all I want is the label to show the item type but it's not saving because every time it fetches the item type of all the tableViews it's only showing the item type label of the most recent item posted

Comment: That doesn't have any obvious connection to the idea that you want to change a to-one relationship to a to-many relationship in code. Why don't you want to create a new version of the data model?

Comment: @TomHarrington I just figured that out about 30 min ago while I was looking through my code. I think I'm going to create a new attribute to Item and just not use the ItemType entity as I can't say item.toItemType.type for some reason. Will update after I test it out.

Comment: So I've come across a problem. @TomHarrington I added a attribute called "type" to Item but when I add it:


`item.type=itemTypes[storePicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)]`

It says "Cannot assign value of type 'Item' to type String?.. If I can't use a string, what can I use for the label to get it to work?

Comment: That error suggests that `itemTypes` is an array of `Item`, not of strings.

Comment: @TomHarrington Okay well I have to use Item so it can save but at the same time I need it to be a string. What should I do?

Comment: Maybe `Item` has a property that's a string? Regardless it's impossible to answer this question post because your question keeps shifting-- what you're asking now has nothing to do with what you posted above.